# What are those small red triangles on the mini map?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Sometimes when I walk around the world, small red triangle appears on the mini map, next to some other marker (e.g. plant or building) then disappears when I keep walking:

> [image]

What do these triangles mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These red triangles are height difference indicators. They are always associated with another marker on the minimap, as you can see with the herb marker. Pointing down, it means the associated marker is below your current height (e.g. underground), vice-versa for upwards pointing triangles.